# Azure Blob Storage CDN Asked for favicon.ico when none exists?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, azure-static-website-hosting

How can favicon.ico be served to browsers making requests to a public Blob Storage Container?

For a publicly-accessible Container at blahblah.blob.core.windows.net, a CDN endpoint was created and SSL cert attached so anyone can get to blobs at https://placeiwant.somewhere/bloblocation/etc/etc/mything.jpg. That works fine.

I noticed in the CDN logs that a browser is looking for https://placeiwant.somewhere/favicon.ico. That file does not exist, and if I point my browser to that URI, I get this error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Error>
<Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code>
<Message>One of the request inputs is out of range. RequestId:nnnnnnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnnnnnnnnnn Time:2020-09-10T13:47:48.5273562Z</Message>
</Error>
```

In addition to Container, I also have a static website set up in $web with CDN layered on top at https://webplaceiwant.somewhere, and a favicon.ico exists there, but I do not see a way to have that favicon.ico served when https://placeiwant.somewhere/ is accessed.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm your findings in 2021: Azure storage still inserts the Container name into the URL (e.g. `bloblocation`). Only $web, when set up as a Static Website, seems to magically strip the container-name, so you can serve something like `favicon.ico` from the root.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the web server will request the `favicon.ico`file when loading websites. When the CDN request responds to 400 error. I also could reproduce this error message displays when a browser is looking for `https://placeiwant.somewhere/favicon.ico`. It looks like it's an expected result.

For the static website set up in `$web` container with CDN. You can just place this `favicon.ico` file under the `$web` container.

[image]

When you browse the static website's primary endpoint, you will see the icon.

[image]

If this does not work for you. You can try to create a storage account v2 via the Azure portal because I have another storage account created by terraform that also appears this issue even I place the same static websites.

Comment: CNAME mysite.com points to blob storage, CNAME mysiteweb.com points to $web. I see no way to have browser on mysite.com get favicon from mysiteweb.com, they are two different URIs.

Comment: To verify it, Can you access the websites via storage blob primary endpoint(like the format in my reply) instead of the CDN endpoint?

Comment: $web Container and blob storage Container are different URIs in Azure Storage just like they are different to the CDN. Navigating to container.web.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob.jpg with a browser still shows browser trying to get container.web.core.windows.net/favicon.ico, existence of $web has absolutely no impact, it has a different URI.

Comment: Storage logs are filling with 400 errors because web browsers from all over the world are trying to get a favicon.ico that doesn't exist in the root of the Storage Account and there is no way to get one that I see. Maybe just add the feature for Storage Accounts?